# Trouble installing yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm running Haskell Platform 2011.2.0.1 and am trying to install Yesod, but keep getting the following error:

```
cabal: cannot configure tls-extra-0.4.1. It requires certificate >=1.0.0 &&
<1.1.0 and cryptocipher >=0.3.0
For the dependency on certificate >=1.0.0 && <1.1.0 there are these packages:
certificate-1.0.0. However none of them are available.
certificate-1.0.0 was excluded because http-enumerator-0.7.1.3 requires
certificate >=0.7 && <0.10
For the dependency on cryptocipher >=0.3.0 there are these packages:
cryptocipher-0.3.0. However none of them are available.
cryptocipher-0.3.0 was excluded because clientsession-0.7.3.2 requires
cryptocipher >=0.2.5 && <0.3
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

There's a brand-new tls-extra which requires newer versions of some packages than other packages allow, so cabal-install can't build a coherent install-plan. If you *really* want the new and shiny tls-extra, you'll have to wait or manually edit the packages with incompatible dependencies, http-enumerator and clientsession, perhaps more, to allow later versions of certificate and cryptocipher.
If you can live with older versions,

```
$ cabal install yesod --constraint="tls-extra < 0.4.1"
```

probably works (perhaps you need more restrictive constraints and constraints on some other packages too).

Comment: This is exactly the case. I've released new versions of http-enumerator and clientsession, so hopefully this is now resolved.

Comment: I haven't tried to actually install it, but I can confirm that cabal-install now can build a coherent install-plan.

Comment: I've installed Yesod now and got the Hello World app running. Thanks for your help!